# C# WPF Dispatcher in richtextbox.Document.Blocks

Tags: c#, wpf

all working ok when Im using in Thread:

```
 richtextbox1.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => { this.richtextbox1.AppendText(text); }));
```

but I get error *"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.*" when Im using in Thread:

```
richtextbox1.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => { this.richtextbox1.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph); }));
```

Im also get this error if I try with richtextbox1.Document = some_FlowDocument

Can't find way how to resolve this in WPF

Comment: Well what is `paragraph`? If it's a UI element that you created in a different thread, that may well be the reason. As an aside, you may well find that using async/await is a simpler way of going about all of this.

Comment: What's the difference between "using in Thread" and "using in Thread", i.e. when does it work and when does it not?

Comment: you can see in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need make FlowDocument and Paragraph in main thread and invoke